# Is "not remembering" the same as "no longer know"?

Tags: meaning, semantics

I thought "not remembering" means "knew before, but stopped knowing". But do I really stop knowing when not remembering? The information could still exist in my brain, but I can not access it currently. It is possible I remember it later, then I know it for sure. But did I start knowing it again, or did I know the whole time?

Not remembering something implies I know I knew it before, but can not tell it now.
But does it imply I currently do not know? Is it correct to say "I don't know my password" when "I don't remember my password"?

Technically both variants are possible: I do not remember my password, but expect to remember it later. And I do not remember the fifth password I ever used in my life, and am sure that I will not remember it later.

Comment: Here's the philosophical take: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/memory/.

Answer (score 2):

"I no longer know" can mean something other than not remembering.  If I'm at work and I haven't contacted a group and they have new members and new procedures I would say.

> I no longer know how to get in touch with them or send them a request.

This would imply not that this item is no longer in my memory, but rather other circumstances outside of me have changed.

Remembering in contrast implies only my own memory.  So should I say:

> I don't remember how to get in touch with them.

I'm referring to myself as the thing that has changed not anything around me.  I'm the one who has forgotten the phone number, email, or process involved.